# Iterate through two dataframes and create a dictionary one data frame that is a substring in strings found in the second dataframe (values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. One is very large and has over 4 million rows of data while the other has about 26k. I'm trying to create a dictionary where the keys are the strings of the smaller data frame. This dataframe (df1) contains substrings or incomplete names and the larger dataframe (df2) contains full names/strings and I want to check if if the substring from df1 is in strings in df2 and then create my dict.

No matter what I try, my code takes long and I keep looking for faster ways to iterate through the df's.

```
org_dict={}
for rowi in df1.itertuples():
    part = rowi.part_name
    full_list = []
    for rowj in df2.itertuples():
        if part in rowj.full_name:
            full_list.append(full_name)
            org_dict[part]=full_list
```

Am I missing a break or is there a faster way to iterate through really large dataframes of way over 1 million rows?

Sample data:

df1

```
    part_name
0   aaa
1   bb
2   856
3   cool
4   man
5   a0
```

df2

```
    full_name
0   aaa35688d
1   coolbbd
2   8564578
3   coolaaa
4   man4857684
5   a03567
```

expected output:

```
{'aaa':['aaa35688d','coolaaa'],
'bb':['coolbbd'],
'856':['8564578']
...}
```

etc

Comment: Please share a few rows of both the dataframes and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that nested for loops perform very badly time-wise as the data grows larger. Luckily, pandas allows us to perform vectorised operations across rows/columns.

I can't properly test without having access to a sample of your data, but I believe this does the trick and performs much faster:

```
org_dict = {substr: df2.full_name[df2.full_name.str.contains(substr)].tolist() for substr in df1.part_name}
```

Comment: added sample data

Comment: Thanks, it seems to still take forever. hasn't finished executing. Not sure if there's anything I can do. I did see a page that compares for loops, iterrows, apply(), and vectorized ops and vectorized ops seemed to be the fastest......

Comment: Yes, I don't think there's any (obvious) way to improve the speed at that point. You'd have to come up with a way to vectorize your comparisons that's faster/better than what the pandas/numpy developers currently enable us to do, which I don't think is a trivial task.

Comment: You could always create a new question such as "fastest way to ...", which is more in sync with what you actually want. Might be worth giving it a shot.